# Change Edge language or locale when running tests

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, selenium-grid

When viewing my app on my local environment, date picklist are in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. However, viewing the same local environment through Selenium, the date picklists are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

When I run my phpunit test to enter `2024-01-30`, it enters the wrong date and later asserts fails.

I must use Edge due to corporate requirements thus I attempted to setup `ChromeOptions` and pass those to Edge (since it's based off Chrome), but it didn't work.

PHP:

```
<?php
use MyPlugin\Tests\TestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverSelect;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;

class escalationTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $driver;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        // Start a browser session
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::microsoftEdge();
        $chrome_options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--lang' => 'en_CA']);
        //$chrome_options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--lang=en_CA']);

        //set language
        $capabilities->setCapability('goog:chromeOptions', $chrome_options);

        // Set the options in the capabilities
        $capabilities->setCapability('platformName', 'linux');

        $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
    }
    ...
}
?>
```

Docker:

```
selenium:
  container_name: selenium
  image: selenium/standalone-edge:latest
  shm_size: 2gb
  environment:
    LANGUAGE: en_CA.UTF-8
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"
    - "7900:7900"
```

**Update**

I tried using a Dockerfile and setting up the container in a specific language. It didn't work.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-edge:latest

ENV LC_ALL en_CA.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_CA.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_CA.UTF-8
```

In the container's terminal:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8
```